# Time complexity of this loop with multiplication

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

I wonder the complexity for this loop in terms of n

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
   for (int j = 1; j * i <= n; j++) {
     minHeap.offer(arr1[i - 1] + arr2[j - 1]);
   }
}
```

What I did was to follow the concept of Big-O and gave it an upper bound -- O(n^2).

Comment: And your own attempt?

Comment: Hey, please see edited version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will involve some math, so get ready :)

Let's first count how many times the line `minHeap.offer(arr1[i - 1] + arr2[j - 1]);` gets invoked. For each `i` from the outer loop, the number of iterations of the inner loop is `n/i` because the condition `j * i <= n` is equivalent to `j <= n/i`. Therefore, the total number of iterations of inner loop is `n/1 + n/2 + n/3 + .. + 1`, or, formally written,

[image]

There is a good approximation for this sum explained in detail e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/486504/how-to-simplify-this-summation-containing-floor), so take a look. Since we are interested only in asymptotic complexity, we can take only the highest order term which is `n * logn`. If there was some `O(1)` operation instead of `minHeap.offer(arr1[i - 1] + arr2[j - 1]);` that would be a solution of your problem. However, the complexity of `offer` method in Java is `O(logk)`, where `k` denotes the current size of priority queue. In our case, priority queue gets larger and larger, so the total running time is `log1 + log2 + ... + log(n * logn) = log(1 * 2 * ... * nlogn) = log((nlogn)!)`.

We can additionally simplify this by using [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), so the final complexity is `O(n * logn * log(n * logn))`.